# Interfaces de rede no docker

Tags: docker

No VirtualBox temos as interfaces de rede, por exemplo, bridge, nat, com hospedeiro, etc...

Minha duvida é, no Docker consigo expor uma porta somente para o host hospedeiro? Algo que no VirtualBox seria equivalente a interface "somente com hospedeiro". A ideia aqui seria um ambiente local de desenvolvimento, isolando o container do restante da rede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao instalar o Docker são criados três tipos de *network* que podem ser consultadas com o comando abaixo:

```
> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
0a9cecbcdf3e        bridge              bridge              local
7787cba5673e        host                host                local
2a6fba328597        none                null                local
```

Ao iniciar um container, o padrão é utilizar o *network* `bridge`, onde o container ingressará a uma rede NAT isolada com outros containers. Essa rede por padrão **já é isolada** do restante da rede.

A *network* `host` nesse caso irá fazer o contrario do que se parece. Ele fará seu container ter contato com a rede do host, algo parecido com o `external` do virtualbox.

Além desses 3 *networks* é possível criar [*networks* customizadas](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#bridge-networks) para ter ainda mais isolamento entre seus containers. Mais informações você pode consultar a documentação do [Docker sobre *networks*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso você precisa de uma rede bridge do Virtualbox.
No entanto por não usar Docker for Windows terá um trabalho adicional que consiste na configuração manual do redirecionamento de portas entre o seu host e a máquina virtual (Virtualbox). Esta configuração fica nas opções avançadas da rede virtual.

O resto segue mesmo padrão do docker, expor portas como parâmetros dos subcomandos run ou start, ou definir no docker-compose.