# Como habilitar acesso de hosts externos ao webserver contido em um container do meu docker host?

Tags: docker

Eu criei um site php com Laravel e para não ter que instalar o ambiente de desenvolvimento laravel em meu pc eu usei o laradock para testar meu projeto. Agora eu quero acessar meu site de um host externo em minha rede local, porem eu só consigo acessar ao site no docker host onde está sendo executado os containers docker laradock. 
[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208295/67223) é explicado como a rede no docker funciona. Eu quero expor meu container que está executando o webserver à rede local. A imagem a seguir explica a situação que quero fazer.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Observações:
1. Eu configurei o laradock para multiplos projetos.
2. Eu executo os seguintes containers com o comando:

> docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: Coloca o seu docker-compose.yml, fica mais fácil de entender

Comment: É o mesmo que o do laradock:https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
Só mudei o banco de dados.